# Checkbox on Custom Metadata Type Record will not update to True

Tags: soql, custom-metadata

I created a Custom Metadata Type with Public Visibility with Object Name "My_App_Settings".

On My_App_Settings, I added a Custom Field:

- Field Label - "Enable Trigger"
- Type - Checkbox
- Field Manageability - Subscriber editable
- Default Value - Unchecked

  I created a new "My_App_Setting" with Master Label "Create Contact Trigger Enable" and selected "Enable Trigger" checkbox.

When I perform a SOQL query on "My_App_Settings" Object I see the row I created "Create Contact Trigger" but the checkbox is always set to false. I don't quite understand why this is the case. Does it have something to do with Subscriber editable setting on the Custom Field?

Comment: Jesse, can you share some code and, maybe, even what the metadata (object and record) looks like (xml or screenshots work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a recently discovered issue with external objects and custom metadata types where checkbox fields with API names of 30 characters or more always return false in queries (though not in the native UI). Might this be what you're seeing?

The known issue link is https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008bS6AAI .

Comment: Hi Avrom, just tested this and it seems to be correct. I shortened it and it returns correctly in queries. Is there a bug I can track on this to see when it is resolved?

Comment: I added the known issue link to my answer.